# How do I best create a button with a left aligned icon and the text centered in the remaining area

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, interface-builder

I need to have a button that looks like this:

[image: example button]

Right now I went for a view with two buttons inside it. But the problem with that is that I can either hook up the two individual buttons to the same outlet, or add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the container view.

I went with the second option because I thought it would be cleaner, but that only works when I disable the buttons (and therefore disable the press-down animation).

Am I on the right track, and should I just find a way to trigger the button's animation when the `UITapGestureRecognizer` calls my method? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a single UIButton and adjust the imageEdgeInsets & titleEdgeInsets.

For a Swift example:

```
extension UIButton {
    func centerTextAndImage(spacing: CGFloat) {
        let insetAmount = spacing / 2
        imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -insetAmount, bottom: 0, right: insetAmount)
        titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: insetAmount, bottom: 0, right: -insetAmount)
        contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: insetAmount, bottom: 0, right: insetAmount)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this centers the (image, text) pair in the button. I need the image outlined to the left, and the text centered in the area between the image and the trailing edge of the button. Also, I need a different color in the area where the image is sitting.

Answer (score 0):

*The size inspector tab for UIButton has an Insets section at the top. Play around with the insets values of title insets and image insets to achieve the desired result.*

[image]

And you don't need to use multiple buttons in a view or tap gesture to achieve this. Just 1 single button would suffice.

Comment: Would this stay consistent across different screen sizes? I imagine this would only work for the screen in which you tuned it.

Comment: Provide a constant width to your button so that the alignment is consistent across all devices.

Comment: That won't work, because I need the button to be almost the entire screen width. So constant width would only look like that on one device type.